# Remove strange hidden charecters from my JSON before deserializing

Tags: c#, regex, serialization

I have some JSON being sent to me that breaks when it is trying to be deserialized. It seems to contain a black diamond with a `?` in it. I cannot see the character but it is obviously there and it is failing on my system.

How do I get rid of this and still leave my JSON intact for deserialization?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a example of what will be in the middle of my JSON:

```
"UDF5" : "�65",
```

I am even open to just removing this property from my JSON altogether via RegEx.

Comment: Could it be encoding problem?

Comment: Is it a BOM? .. Your question is less than perfect. Where is this "diamond"? The first in the response? Why is it "obviously there" when you can't see it? How did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: A BOM is a byte-order mark... a sequence of bytes preprended to a string to indicate encoding info. If you're using the wrong encoding, it may not pick this up.

Comment: In my database when I look at the text I cannot see it, in a web page it shows as a black diamond with a questions mark - something is hidden there that is causing me issues

Comment: see here: "UDF5" : "�65",

Comment: You should fix the code that is generating that, not your consumer.

Comment: agreed svick but at this moment that it is not an option

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U%2BFFFD#Replacement_character  Most commonly seen when you read text with the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered for: [remove piece of string (JSON string ) with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554147/remove-piece-of-string-json-string-with-regex/14554202#14554202) and based on the formatting you provide in that question (and I am assuming will edit into this one):

Assuming I can rely on the formatting you show above and it is one of these per regex being run this can be accomplished as simply as something like

`([\S\s]*\"])\"UDF5\" : \"[\S\s]*?\",([\S\s]*)`

Using the back reference $1$2 referencing the parts before and after the UDF5 field to write back out.

If there is a newline there to remove I am not doing it right now. This could be better - if someone else has time to correct or provide an additional answer. But in the interests of getting you an emergency fix I hope this helps.