# remove piece of string (JSON string ) with regex

Tags: c#, regex, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remove strange hidden charecters from my JSON before deserialinzing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553954/remove-strange-hidden-charecters-from-my-json-before-deserialinzing)

I have some JSON and I need to remove one of the elements in it before I can deserialize it.

I have some bad data coming into my system and I need to strip it out,  not the best solution but this is an emergency.

so I am looking to remove a property from my JSON.

Here is a sample:

```
{
 "UDF4" : "",
 "ProductID" : 0,
 "Dimensions" : "",
 "weight" : 0,
 "Category" : "",
 "OrderID" : 0,
 "ManufacturerID" : 439,
 "CatalogCode" : "BARB",
 "ItemID" : "BARB13HIV",
 "Description" : "BARB13HIV",
 "BasePrice" : 0,
 "OrderItemID" : 0,
 "Price" : 44,
 "UDF5" : "�65",
 "UDF1" : "13HIV",
 "Qty" : 3,
 "UPC" : "BARB13HIV",
 "DiscountValue" : 0,
 "Cubes" : 0,
 "CatalogName" : "BARBARA COSGROVE LAMPS",
 "UDF2" : "",
 "ItemName" : "13\" Painted parchment ivory",
 "ModifierListID" : 0,
 "UnitOfMeasure" : "",
 "SortOrder" : 36,
 "SubTotal" : 132,
 "PhotoName" : "barb-13hiv",
 "OverrridePrice" : 0,
 "UDF3" : "",
 "AdditionalImageCount" : 0,
 "OrderGUID" : "3DFB932C-2F88-4C44-9417-251EABE1B863",
 "CompleteItemID" : "BARB13HIV",
 "PiecesBox" : 0,
 "SalesRepID" : 0,
 "Source" : "",
 "HasLineItemDiscount" : 0}
```

I need to remove the UDF5 portion of this string while leaving the JSON intact - the value for UDF is variable.

Comment: Please don't re-post the same question. If you have more information to add, you should update your previous answer.

Comment: it is, I am trying a different route and I will kill the other question - I am not trying to spam the system but this is an emergency as it affects an ordering system.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I can rely on the formatting you show above and it is one of these per regex being run this can be accomplished as simply as something like

`([\S\s]*\"])\"UDF5\" : \"[\S\s]*?\",([\S\s]*)`

Using the back reference `$1$2` referencing the parts before and after the UDF5 field to write back out.

If there is a newline there to remove I am not doing it right now. This could be better - if someone else has time to correct or provide an additional answer. But in the interests of getting you an emergency fix I hope this helps.